# Thai Font / Character not working?

Tags: html, fonts, doctype, meta

[image]

I'm using this doctype and meta tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="th" lang="th">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="th">
</head>
```

I also have thai fonts included in the css. What might be the problem?

Thank you guys!

Comment: on a technological points: you're using ancient HTML4 synax, not modern HTML5, which is what your doctype claims you're using, so either fix that doctype, or start using HTML5 syntax instead (I strongly recommend the latter). Once you've done that, search google or the like for "using @font-face" and then follow the many many results.